# Strange behaviour for threads in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, multithreading

```
public void WriteToLog(string Msg)
{
    //Write to Log
}

public static void Apple()
{
    WriteToLog("Apple Started"); // third log line
}

public void CallFunction()
{
    Thread EmailThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Apple));
    WriteToLog(EmailThread.ThreadState.ToString()); // first log line
    EmailThread.Start();
    WriteToLog(EmailThread.ThreadState.ToString()); // second log line
}
```

in the log file, I get first line and second line. but i can't get the third line.

I can get the third line if i simply  call the `Apple` function.

and the first line is `Unstarted` and second line is `running`.

there is no third line.

when i write `while` loop under the `second log line`,

```
while(EmailThread.ThreadState.ToString()=="Running")
{
    WriteToLog("Thread running");
}
```

It becomes infinite loop. I had to stop the IIS.

Is it a strange behavior?

All the functions inside `Apple` doesn't seem working either.

but the thread state is running..

I m lost. Any idea?

or is it because of the new thread, it can't write to log file? the same log file? but i already tried 2 different log files. It is still not working...

and I wrote the function to write to log file at the start of the `Apple`.

Comment: Why are you even using threads? you seem to lack any understanding on how to write multithreaded code which is a good reason for me to believe that you don't need it in the first place. ASP.NET has its own thread pool, and will effectively multithread incoming requests for you. You don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: It is not that I am using the thread.. but the code that I m rectifying is using threads..

Comment: what log are you using? there can be some file locking going on which cannot be seen from code you are providing. show actual write to log code, cause I am pretty sure Thread.Start() is working

Comment: @x0n: If the work done in his EmailThread takes more than a few milliseconds to complete, there's absolutely no reason not to perform it on another thread.  If he does it on the same thread the request is handled on, the request will block until the potentially long-running action is complete.  Granted, there are other possibly better architectures depending on the actual problem (a queue comes to mind), but you are wrong that there's no reason to multithread the request.

Comment: @william: What happens when you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub: It is just a simple log file. And i dun think it is the log file that is blocking.. coz the code is not working.. that's why i m putting log to debug. and Thread.Start() is working.. coz the log file says the state of the thread is running.. but nth inside `Apple` is working.. i simply called the function. it is working.. And I m not sure why the previous guy used the thread.. and I dun really want to remove the thread..

Comment: @Eric J.: I can't really step through the debugger.. coz i dun hav the whole solution.. that's why i m putting log files.

Comment: @william: Can you use .NET 4? (threading is simpler in .NET 4)

Comment: @Eric J.: Sorry bro, the code is in .Net 2.0.. the company doesn't allow me to upgrade the .Net version..

Comment: @william: Also, you don't want to loop as show in your `while` loop.  That will cause the CPU to stay very busy in a tight loop checking for the other thread to complete, wasting resources.  Look at `Thread.Join` if you really need to wait for the other thread to complete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3388/discussion-between-eric-j-and-william)

Comment: @Eric: tkz let's continue in chat..

Comment: Your simple log file write probably isn't thread safe.  You may need to add a lock to protect the log file.

Comment: I removed the logging part. but it still doesn't seem working..

Answer (score 1):

Is the logging mechanism multi-threaded?

I would suggest you add a critical section to your code to ensure that the logging is only occuring from one thread at a time, otherwise they could be flushing the buffer or overwriting the output or something funny like that.

To do this implement something like this:

```
static readonly object threadLock = new object();

public void WriteToLog(string Msg)   
{
    lock(threadLock)
    {   
        //Write to Log
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATED**

Also I would try not making the thread a local variable. It is possible it is getting finalised before it's code is executing. Define it as a field on the class like so:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private Thread EmailThread;

   public void WriteToLog(string Msg) 
   { 
       //Write to Log 
   } 

   public static void Apple() 
   { 
       WriteToLog("Apple Started"); // third log line 
   } 

   public void CallFunction() 
   { 
       EmailThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Apple)); 
       WriteToLog(EmailThread.ThreadState.ToString()); // first log line 
       EmailThread.Start(); 
       WriteToLog(EmailThread.ThreadState.ToString()); // second log line 
  } 
}
```

Comment: no there are several threads that i never touched.. which means those threads doesn't hav write to log functions.. they never worked either..

Comment: @william Let me know if this helps any.